# Can't install Windows 98 SE in virtualbox - SUWIN caused a General Protection Fault in module <unknown>

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-98

I get this error when installing Windows 98 Second Edition on virtualbox. my host is Mac OsX.
[image: install error]

the guest settings are the following:

Base memory: 64 MB
Boot Order: Floppy, Optical, Hard Disk
Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging
Video Memory: 10 MB

Why I am getting that error and how can I bypass it?

---

EDIT:

Also get these errors when i click on close:

```
W98SETUP caused a General Protection Fault in module GDI.EXE at 0001:0246
```

---

```
W98SETUP caused a General Protection Fault in module USER.EXE at 0001:40B6
```

---

```
Standart Mode: Bad Fault in MS-DOS Extender.
Fault: 000D Stack Dump: 000 000 0070
Raw fault frame: EC=000 IP=5EF7 CS=0367 FL=3087 SP=FFEE SS=02C7
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a bug in VirtualBox 5.0. I haven't reported it yet <sup>I'll get around to it</sup> but for the time being I downgraded to version 4.3.28, and the old Windows boots fine.

Update: This *[should](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14811)* be fixed by VirtualBox 5.0.22, although I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Installing virtualbox 4.3.28 solved my problem. thank you very much

Comment: Yes, it’s fixed. Works for me in VirtualBox 5.0.26 as well as 5.1.6.

Answer (score 15):

Problem:

Windows 98SE is incompatible with the newer hardware that VirutalBox virtualizes; specifically when hardware resources are passed-through from the host directly.

Solution:

In VirtualBox, disable the hardware acceleration for that VM.

To do so:

- Right-click VM.
- Choose *Settings*.
- Choose *System*.
- Choose the *Acceleration* tab.
- Un-check Enable VT-x/AMD-V.
- Save changes, try again.

[image]

Comment: same thing.... same error

Comment: I tried also with 300mb of disk, but the second error is: `Standard Mode: Invalid DMPI return from 0367:5F92`

Comment: Hmm, by default it _doesn't_ pass through most resources. And Win98 is fine with a few unknown VBox-specific PCI devices showing up.

Comment: This answer solved the issue for me using a Linux host.

Comment: This answer solved the issue while installing Win 98 SE (fr) on a Windows 8.1 host - VirtualBox 5.

Comment: This answer helped me.

Comment: This "solution" works,but virtual machine will become very slow

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get around this error by using the `Paravirtualization` setting to `Legacy` (found under System => Acceleration in the VM settings).

Answer (score 0):

A default install of Virtualbox on Mac OS X assumes VT-x availability. This is because all of the Mac hardware lineup supports it. In order to disable VT-x extensions to allow a Windows 98 to install/work, do this in a Terminal window (sub in your machine name inside the quotes):

`VBoxManage modifyvm "My Windows 98 VM Name Here" --hwvirtex off`

Source: http://blog.vaibhavbajpai.com/2012/12/17/disabling-vt-x-on-virtualbox/